# ODOO 8 on_change

Tags: onchange, odoo

Please I am facing somes problems with the new odoo 8 api, I have the following classes

```
class TypeProcessus(models.Model):
    _name = 'atom.promaintenance.type.processus'
    name = fields.Char()
    id_phases = fields.One2many('atom.promaintenance.phases','id_processus','Liste des Phases')

class Phases(models.Model):
    _name = 'atom.promaintenance.phases'
    name = fields.Char()
    autoriserCommentaire = fields.Boolean()
    autoriserPiecesJointes = fields.Boolean()
    id_processus = fields.Many2one('atom.promaintenance.type.processus')
    parent_id = fields.Many2one('atom.promaintenance.phases','Phase Parent', select=True,      ondelete='cascade')
    commentaire = fields.Text()

    @api.one
    @api.onchange('name')
    def phases_write(self):
      print 'test'

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="atom_promaintenance_type_processus">
<field name="name">atom.promaintenance.type.processus.form</field>
<field name="model">atom.promaintenance.type.processus</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">

        <form string="Type Processus" >
            <sheet>
            <h1>UPDATED</h1>
                <field name="name" />
                    <tree string="note_evaluation_tree" editable="bottom">
                        <field name="id_phases"  />
                    </tree>
            </sheet>
        </form>

</field>
</record>
```

First of all my problem is when Creating a new Processus, and adding phases, there is a relation parent child between phases and the drop down list for parent stay empty unless u save the processus to make them available.

i managed to add onChange event to the phases to persist them to database but i can't figure out how to save those records with the new api system, thank you

Comment: You can't use onchange methods to save records. I don't really understand what you want to do here. If you want to change how records are saved/created, you must override `create` and/or `write` methods or call them in your methods if you need to create/update some related records.

Comment: i cant find your problem , what is the relation between onChange() and store records ? so you tell whats the actually problem

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what I understand, you need to use the widget one2many_list in the XML code, which by the way, I think is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="atom_promaintenance_type_processus">
    <field name="name">atom.promaintenance.type.processus.form</field>
    <field name="model">atom.promaintenance.type.processus</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Type Processus" >
            <sheet>
            <h1>UPDATED</h1>
                <field name="name" />
                <field name="id_phases" widget="one2many_list">
                    <tree string="note_evaluation_tree" editable="bottom">
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="autoriserCommentaire"/>
                        <field name="autoriserPiecesJointes"/>
                        <field name="parent_id"/>
                        <field name="commentaire"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

The widget will allow you to add phases for a processus and then save it.

Answer (score 0):

The new API uses `self` for all the record modifications. So in your case, if you want to change the `name`, write like this:

```
@api.one
@api.onchange('name')
def onchange_name(self):
    self.name = 'what you want to save'
```